# array inheritance question in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, inheritance

```
function ClassA() { this.a=[]; this.aa=100; }
function ClassB() {  }

ClassB.prototype = new ClassA;
ClassB.prototype.b=function(){return "classbb"};

for (var l in ClassB.prototype){

    Array.prototype[l] = ClassB.prototype[l]; 
}
var array1 = [];
alert(array1.b());
```

Can

> Array.prototype[l] =
>   ClassB.prototype[l]

be replaced by

> Array.prototype[l] = ClassB[l]

? Could someone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't.`ClassB` has no property `b`, `ClassB.prototype` has.
If you do, in `alert(array1.b());` `array1.b` will be `undefined`

Comment: @wong2. If I want to define ClassB.b, how should I do? Thanks

Comment: @jsnewman I'm not sure if I understand what you want to do...You can define ClassB.b by   `function ClassB() {}; ClassB.b = function(){return "classbb"};`

Comment: @wong2: Could you tell me the difference between ClassB.b and ClassB.prototype.b? Thank you very much. And what does ClassB.property mean?

Comment: @jsnewman If you define `ClassB.prototype.b` to some value, then every instance created by `new ClassB();`(like `var class_b = new ClassB();`) will have a property `b`, but if you define `ClassB.b`, then `b` is just a property of `ClassB`(who is a function, and also an object).Is that clear?

Comment: @wong2: function ClassB() {
this.b = function(){return "classbb"};
}
ClassB.b = function(){return "classBB"};                                                          What is the difference between this.b and ClassB.b?

Comment: @jsnewman if you use `function ClassB() { this.b = function(){return "classbb"}; }` then ClassB don't have property `b`, only when you call `var class_b = new ClassB()`, `class_b` has property `b`. You can look at Nicholas Zakas's book "Professional JavaScript for Web Developers" in the 6th chapter.